# Calculate the volume using triple integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Calculate the volume inside the region limited by the cone $$z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$ and the paraboloid $$z= 2-(x^2+y^2)$$.

I did [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVwbe.png) to calculate it. I thought it would be correct, but it wasn't. This was on my past test, by the way. I knew it could've been easier to do in cylindrical coordinates, but I wasn't confident enough and hesitated and got it wrong. My professor solved it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xm3k.png).

How could I have solved it the way I did it and got the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in thinking the lower bound is not a cone.

[image]

The $z$ height of transition is when $r = 2 - r^2$, that is, when $r=1$... and thus $z=1$.

So the volume of the cone is $\frac{1}{3} \pi 1^2 1 = \pi/3$.

Integrating over the paraboloid:

$V = \int\limits_{z=1}^2 2 \pi \sqrt{2-z} dz = \frac{4 \pi}{3}$ so the total volume is $\frac{5 \pi}{3}$.

You never need triple integrals.

Comment: I mean, I'm pretty sure the point of the problem was to use triple integrals as we'd seen in class. You did get a different result than the one my professor got, though. Was he incorrect?

Comment: Usually the point is not to get the volume but to be able to set up bounds in $3$D. Professors get boring and usually only ask for the volume instead of placing an integrand, but it is skill that is the focus of the class anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In cylindrical coordinates the integral can be set up as

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_{r}^{2-r^2}r\:dz\:dr\:d\theta$$

or spherical coordinates we have

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt{2}} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\rho^2\sin\phi\:d\rho\:d\phi\:d\theta + \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\sqrt{2}}^2 \int_0^{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{4\rho^2-7}}{2\rho}\right)}\rho^2\sin\phi\:d\rho\:d\phi\:d\theta$$

since this is the only integration order that is "doable" as an integral. Here, cylindrical coordinates is the clear winner in terms of ease.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Would it have been possible to get the volume in regular cartisian coordinates? EDIT: what I mean is was I close to getting the correct answer?